# 'if' statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Consider the following data:

```
library(Benchmarking)
x <- c(4,2,4,6,9,2)
y <- c(2,1,5,2,10,4)
k <- c(25,25,25,30,30,30)
d <- data.frame(x,y,k)
```

Now I want to do the following calculation:

```
e1 <- dea(d$x, d$y, XREF = d$x, YREF = d$y)
```

But I want to change it, so `XREF` and `YREF` only consider column `x` in `d` if `k = 25`. Something like:

```
e1 <- dea(d$x, d$y, XREF = d$x if k = 25, YREF = d$y if k = 25)
```

But this does not work. Can someone show me how to code this in `R`?

Comment: What about filtering `d` before using the `dea` function? `d <- d[d$k == 25,]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with(subset(d, k == 25), dea(d$x, d$y, XREF = x, YREF = y))`

Where `d$` notation uses the original full data, and direct `x` and `y` refers to the variables from the `subset`.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, you could use `apply` to easily do this.

If you want XREF and YREF to only consider column x when k = 25, then:

```
apply(d, 1, function (df) if (df["k"] == 25) {
  dea(df["x"], df["y"], XREF = df["x"], YREF = df["x"]) 
  } else {
      dea(df["x"], df["y"], XREF = df["x"], YREF = df["y"])
    }
)
```

This is different to the example code you show. That would be equivalent to:

```
apply(d, 1, function (df) if (df["k"] == 25) {
  dea(df["x"], df["y"], XREF = df["x"], YREF = df["y"]) 
  } else {
      dea(df["x"], df["y"])
    }
)
```